# Set of rational numbers generated by some rules

Tags: nt.number-theory

Define a set $S$ as the smallest subset of the set of positive rational numbers satisfying the following rules:

- (i) $1$ is in $S$
- (ii) If $a/b$ is in $S$, where the fraction is written in irreducible form (that is, $a$ and $b$ have greatest common divisor 1) then $\frac b{2\cdot a}$ is in $S$ (in other words, $q\in S$ implies $\frac1{2\cdot q}\in S$).
- (iii) If $a/b$ and $c/d$ are in $S$, where they are written in irreducible form then $(a+c)/(b+d)$ is in $S$.

Can you describe which numbers are in $S$?

Comment: Sorry in the second condition I wrote a is written in lowest terms it will be ----- a/b is written in the lowest terms

Comment: I understand that stern brocot trees may make the answer but cannot explain the presence of 1/0 & 0/1 for that 1/1 is in S

Comment: Previously posted to (and closed at) m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692249/set-theory-problem-finding-elements-for-given-condition

Comment: Well you don’t get 1/0 and 0/1. However, you get 1/1 and 1/2, and thus using mediants you get the part of the tree between 1/2 and 1/1, i.e., $\mathbb Q\cap[1/2,1]$. And that’s all, by Joel’s observation.

Comment: Can someone post an answer concerning these trees?

Comment: Actually attending a seminar on wheel of numbers there a pattern of number was shown and told about the farey sequence and stern brocot trees . I was struggling with this problem for some days . So I thought it may give the solution

Comment: By (i),  $(-1)/(-1)$ (which is equal to $1/1$) is in $S$.  By (iii), it follows that $(1+(-1))/(1+(-1))=0/0$ is in $S$.  But $0/0$ does not represent any real number.  Therefore there is no set $S$ satisfying your conditions.

Comment: Steven, it would be charitable to interpret the question as insisting, say, that denominators should be positive, in which case $S$ does exist.

Comment: Sir how I can say that (-a/b) is not in S where a and b both are from natural number set?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins :  Yes, and you showed a lot more charity than I did by not only adopting this interpretation but actually contributing a useful insight.  But let me gently suggest that there is also some charity in taking a moment to nudge an apparent novice toward a more rigorous prose style.

Answer (score 7):

It is indeed true that $S=\mathbb{Q}\cap [1/2,1]$. The inclusion $S\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\cap [1/2,1]$ is observed in the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295641) by Joel David Hamkins. The opposite inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\cap [1/2,1]\subseteq S$ follows from the fact that $\{1/2,1\}\subset S$ and basic properties of [Farey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) sequence.

Comment: Isn't this maybe a comment on [@JoelDavidHamkins's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295641) rather than a separate answer?

Comment: @LSpice possibly. But my general experience is that the comments often remain much less read than the answers, and people proceed thinking on something already written in the comments.

Comment: I think this should remain an answer, not a comment, because it provides the complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

To start things off, here is a simple observation: the set $S$ is contained in the rational interval $\mathbb{Q}\cap[\frac 12,1]$, the rational numbers $\frac ab$ where $0<a\leq b\leq 2a$.

The reason is that $1/1$ has this form and your transformations preserve the property of being in this interval. If $a\leq b\leq 2a$, then $b/2a$ obeys the requirement, since $b\leq 2a\leq 2b$. And if $a/b$ and $c/d$ obey the requirement, then so does $(a+c)/(b+d)$, since $a+c\leq b+d\leq 2a+2c=2(a+c)$.

Comment: Sir, I  do not understand your statement as you said 0<a≤b≤2a. If I take 1/4 from [1/2,1] the inequality is not obeyed

Comment: For positive integers, $a\leq b$ means $\frac ab\leq 1$, and $b\leq 2a$ means $\frac 12\leq \frac ab$. So $0<a\leq b\leq 2a$ is satisfied by exactly the fractions in the interval from $\frac 12$ to $1$.

Comment: @user542993, note that $1/4$ is not in $[1/2, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have 1/2, you don't need Rule (ii) anymore. 
In other words, the problem could read as follows:

The set S contains some real numbers, according to the following three rules.

(i) 1/1 is in S (ii) 1/2 is in S, and (iii) If a/b and c/d are in S, where they are written in the lowest terms then (a+c)/(b+d) is in S.

These rules are exhaustive: if these rules do not imply that a number is in S, then that number is not in S. Can you describe which numbers are in S?

The answer will still be the same: S=Q∩[1/2,1]

Answer (score 0):

*Way-way more is true than stated by the OP's *Question* (or even the earlier answers).*

---

Let notation $\ a/b\ $ stand for an ordered pair $ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ of non-negative integers that are relatively prime.

Such pairs $\ a/b\ $ are interpreted as positive rational numbers except for the single case of $\ 1/0\ $ that is interpreted as $\ \infty.\ $

Let two such pairs, $\ A/B\ $ and $\ a/b\ $ be called neighbors (in **this order!**) $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ their determinant is $\ 1,\ $ i.e.
$$ A\cdot b-B\cdot a\ =\ 1. $$

For instance
$$ \frac11\quad\frac12 $$
are neighbors.

Let's start with an arbitrary pair of neighbors as the top row of table $\ T(A/B\,\ a/b),\ $ and lets obtain the next rows of the table (in a Pascal triangle manner) by applying the median operation in order to obtain a new row from the last row by:

$$ A/B\quad a/b $$
$$ A/B\quad(A+a)/(B+b)\quad a/b $$
$$ A/B\quad(2\!\cdot\! A+a)/(2\!\cdot\! a+b)\quad(A+a)/(B+b)
   \quad (A+2\!\cdot\! a)/(B+2\cdot b)\quad a/b $$
etc.

Obviously, each two consecutive elements of arbitrary row of the table are neighbors. The following two basic theorems hold (*have you seen the second one in print?*):

- Let $\ X/x\ $ be a pair of relatively prime non-negative integers such that $\ A/a\ge X/x\ge B/b,\ $ i.e. $\ A\cdot x\ge a\cdot X\ $ and $\ X\cdot b\ge x\cdot B.\ $ Then $\ X/x\ $ appears in a row of the table (hence in allm next rows too).
- Arbitrary pair of neighbors, $\ X/x\quad Y/y\ $, such that
  $$ A/a\ \ge\ X/x\ >\ Y/y\ \ge\ B/B $$
  appears as consecutive elements of a row in the table **exactly** one time.

---

---

**Remarks**

- Table $\ T(A/a\,\ B/b)\ $ is a subtable of table $\ T(1/0\,\ 0/1).\ $ This last table represents all non-negative rational numbers as well as $\ \infty:=1/0.$
- Table $\ T(1/0\,\ 0/1)\ $ corresponds to the general special monoid generated by the two "*two by two*" 0-1 triangular matrices; it immediately tells you that it is a free monoid in two generators, and it tells you about everything there is about this monoid. **Indeed**, given a pair of neighbors, the median produces two pairs of neighbors that can be equivalently defined by applying the two triangular matrices to the given pair of neighbors.
  (*I am not able to recall the name of the author of table $\ T(1/\, 0/1).\ $ I seem to remember that this name was mentioned in a small monograph by Knuth*)
- Table $\ T(1/0\,\ 0/1)\ $ may serve as a foundation for the elementary diophantine (rather better than the otherwise impressive Farey sequence) -- this table is in a simple way directly related to the continued fractions.